# statistics - dnd dice roll plus modifiers outcome probability

Tags: probability, dice

In a hypothetical dungeons and dragons scenario, suppose that your character have a strength modifier of +5. You have an opponent, a wimpy peasant with a strength modifier of +1.

you both get into a fight (aka contest). when this happens, you both each roll a 1d20 then add modifiers. whoever gets the higher roll plus modifiers wins the contest. In case of tie, there will be a re-roll until someone wins

How do I calculate the probability that your character wins the contest?

EDIT: in this situation, modifiers are immediately added after the roll

Comment: You appear to be assuming that we know what "modifiers" are.  Do you simply add your modifier to whatever the die shows?

Comment: Sorry i fixed it already. To answer your question, yes. Simply add it to whatever the die shows.

Comment: Thanks.  Just go case by case.  If the strong player, $S$, rolls a $1$, then $S$ wins immediately if the weak player, $W$, throws one of  $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and there's a tie if $W$ throws $5$.  Do that for each of $S's$ rolls. Of course, there's a simple pattern that you'll see early on.

Comment: is there a monte-carlo approach to this problem? i'm trying to program this in python so i could get a better grasp of the concept

Comment: Well, there's always a monte carlo approach, but why bother?  The exact method I sketched is no more difficult.

Comment: The exact method:  just count the winners for $S$.  There are $400$ possible pairs of rolls.  Of those, $16$ are ties.  (a tie here is a pair like $(1,5)$ or $(16,20)$).  If $S$ rolls a $1$ there are $4$ winners.  If $S$ rolls a $2$ there are $5$ winners, and so on up to, if $S$ rolls a $16$ there are $19$ winners.  Just count those.